# Change font size of UITextField or UITextView with UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uipickerview

I want to change the font size in **`UITextField`** or in **`UITextView`** with using **`UIPickerView`**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating an NSArray to contain the font sizes in your picker. NSArray gets fussy if you try to give it primitives, so use [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)] when adding the font sizes to your array. Once you have an array, populate the picker and then set up the picker's didSelectRow: method.

In my example, assume that "data" is my array of numbers, "pickerView" is an IBOutlet for a UIPickerView, and "label" is another outlet for a UILabel. All of this code would be in a single view controller:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
        // pickerView is going to get its data from this class
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.dataSource = self;

        [super viewDidLoad];
   }

    #pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate methods
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        //Log it out for debugging
        NSLog(@"data for row #%d = %@",row,[data objectAtIndex:row]);

        // return data for current row
        return [data objectAtIndex:row];
    }


    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:[data objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
```

I'm not sure if you plan on storing this value, changing labels, or what... but this should cover the concepts you will need to utilize.

EDIT: Formatting and viewDidLoad added to original post.

Comment: hi what is "fontName" in the code
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:[data objectAtIndex:row]];
    }

Comment: The fontName is actually a bit code left in from my own project that I copied from. You can see the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontWithName:size:).

For the purposes of the original question, you do not need to use this if you are fine with the default font. If this is the case, go ahead and use [fontWithSize:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIFont/fontWithSize:).

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate of UIPickerView and set the font of UITextField again..